# Declaring Backbone Collection in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to figure out the right way to declare a model for a Backbone Collection in CoffeeScript. Let me demonstrate with an example:

```
class MyApp.Collections.Likes extends Backbone.Collection
  constructor: (@models, @options) ->
  model: MyApp.Models.Like
```

When I initialize this collection and create a new model, it fails.

```
likes = new MyApp.Collections.Likes
like = new likes.model // same result for likes.model.new

TypeError: Result of expression 'likes.model' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Looking at the compiled JavaScript, the model is defined as follows:

```
MyApp.Collections.Likes = (function() {
  __extends(Likes, Backbone.Collection);
  function Likes(models, options) {
    this.models = models;
    this.options = options;
  }
  Likes.prototype.model = MyApp.Models.Like; // <--
  return Likes;
})();
```

I could define the model in two ways that will work:

---

### Solution 1

```
class MyApp.Collections.Likes extends Backbone.Collection
  constructor: (@models, @options) ->
  model: -> MyApp.Models.Like // Notice the ->
```

Which compiles it to:

```
MyApp.Collections.Likes = (function() {
  __extends(Likes, Backbone.Collection);
  function Likes(models, options) {
    this.models = models;
    this.options = options;
  }
  Likes.prototype.model = function() { // <-- added to the prototype as a function
    return MyApp.Models.Like;
  }
  return Likes;
})();
```

### Solution 2

```
class MyApp.Collections.Likes extends Backbone.Collection
  constructor: (@models, @options) ->
  @model: MyApp.Models.Like // Notice the @
```

Which compiles it to:

```
MyApp.Collections.Likes = (function() {
  __extends(Likes, Backbone.Collection);
  function Likes(models, options) {
    this.models = models;
    this.options = options;
  }
  Likes.model = function() { // <-- not added to prototype
    return MyApp.Models.Like;
  }
  return Likes;
})();
```

---

I'm pretty sure **Solution 1** is the better solution. However, lots of sites I've looked at with tutorials define it without the `->` or `@`.

Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

There isn't anything wrong with the `Like` model, it's pretty vanilla:

```
class MyApp.Models.Like extends Backbone.Model
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate your error. Here's my code:

```
class Like extends Backbone.Model

class Likes extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Like

likes = new Likes
like = new likes.model
console.log like instanceof Like  # true
```

Is it possible that you made a typo somewhere? In particular, is `MyApp.Models.Like` defined at the point where you write `model: MyApp.Models.Like`? The tests

```
console.log MyApp.Collections.Likes::model?
```

and

```
console.log MyApp.Collections.Likes::model is MyApp.Models.Like
```

should both give you `true`. And if they do, then `new likes.model` should be equivalent to `new MyApp.Models.Like`.

Comment: Could you show me your compiled JavaScript for the model and collection?

Comment: @Jey Why not just copy+paste the code into the Try CoffeeScript box at http://coffeescript.org?

Comment: Arg, I've been writing this app TDD and haven't bothered to check this in a browser. The problem actually was in my Jasmine configuration, which was loading all compiled JavaScript files `public/javascript/compiled/**/*.js`. This doesn't account for dependency ordering, which resulted in this error. Thanks for proving what I did initially worked in the browser.

Comment: If you're going all-out TDD, you may want to use [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch). Then you can test under Node and concatenate everything for the browser. I ran my test code under Node, since it's fast to set up (you just `npm install backbone` and then put `Backbone = require 'backbone'` at the top of your file).

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen when you write

```
like = likes.model.new
```

? That syntax works in Ruby, but in CoffeeScript, it just assigns the `new` property of `likes.model` to `like`. In this case, that's just going to be `undefined`. Try

```
like = new likes.model
```

instead.

Comment: That was actually a typo on my part, I was just testing something and forgot to switch it back. I've tried both `new likes.model` and `likes.model.new`. Same error. [Correcting my question]

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know I'm late to this party but I wanted to add that every time I've seen this problem it's been because programmers forget that classes in coffeescript are a leaky abstraction, and that their declarations aren't read before execution -- in this case the Model needs to be defined *before* the compiled js attempts to add it to the Collection's prototype.